# I don't see the expected view in angular JS, maybe binding issue?

Tags: html, angularjs

So I am trying to build the simplest Angular JS application and no idea what I am doing wrong.
It is made of 4 files:

1. index.html - which I use like a layout to display main.html
2. app1.js - used for defining simple routing rules like /main should redirect to main.html in combination with MainController; when it doesn't find a valid path, revert to a default which equals the previous path
3. MainController.js - I just have some timer functions here
4. main.html - displays a search button and search textbox

For some reason, I can't see mainvtemplate from my index.html which should redirect me to /main.

Here is the code:

index.html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="githubViewer">

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.3.0-beta.5" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.5/angular.js"></script>
    <script data-require="angular-route@*" data-semver="1.2.14" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.14/angular-route.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <script src="MainController.js"></script>
  </head>

    <body>
        <h1>Github Viewer</h1>
        <div ng-view></div>
    </body>


</html>
```

the app1.js

```
(function(){

    var app = angular.module("githubViewer", ["ngRoute"]);

    app.config(function($routeProvider){
        $routeProvider
            .when("/main", {
                templateUrl: "main.html",
                controller: "MainController"
            })
            .otherwise({redirectTo:"/main"});
    });

}());
```

the main.html file:

```
<div>
    {{ countdown }}
    <form name="searchUser" ng-submit="search(username)">
        <input type="search" required="" ng-model="username" />
        <input type="submit" value="Search" />
    </form>
</div>
```

You may ignore the countdown, this is a timer created in MainController.js. I render its simplified logic:

```
(function() {

    var app = angular.module("githubViewer");

    var MainController = function($scope, $interval, $location) {

        $scope.search = function(username) {
           if(countdownInterval)    {
               $interval.cancel(countdownInterval);
               $scope.countdown = null;
           }
           $location.path("/user/" + username);
        };

        $scope.countdown = 5;
    };

    app.controller("MainController", MainController);

}());
```

Isn't weird I'm not able to see the search button and search textbox? Maybe I am missing sth really obvious here.

Comment: angular "1.3.0-beta.5" ... upgrade to 1.5.X at least

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
in your index.html 
<script src="app.js"></script>

replace with
<script src="app1.js"></script>


main.html
<div ng-app="githubViewer" ng-controller="MainController ">// add ng app ang nd cntroller
    {{ countdown }}
    <form name="searchUser" ng-submit="search(username)">
        <input type="search" required="" ng-model="username" />
        <input type="submit" value="Search" />
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you Manoj. I still get angular.js:8380 Failed to load file:///...Desktop/main.html: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https. But I think with this the main problem was solved.